Acreage measurements not aligning (small polygons within larger do not total to same amount) using ArcGIS Pro
I am struggling with figuring out why my acreage totals do not match.   I have a main polygon that totals 73.28 acres but the small polygons within that polygon total 77.22 . It's an area for a project where work is being done (felling/masticating).  I map the areas completed every month and make sure the totals reported are correct.  I am working with ArcGIS Pro 3.2.
Each total for the last 4 months measures correctly, but now when I add those measurements within the Unit treated (encompasses the 4 monthly polygons), they don't coincide.  The polygon for the unit is 73.28 acres but the total for the 4 polygons within the unit total 77.22.  They line up exactly inside the unit.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Bdzo8VE58uYHyOYpWTm83tkNcHVdwPn/view?usp=drive_link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19O-LFYag_yRxpqe_0Lf2biGE4nJAK2P2/view?usp=drive_link
Map-
v Spatial Reference
Projected Coordinate System NAD 1983 StatePlane California III FIPS 0403 (US Feet)
Projection
Lambert Conformal Conic
Data-
Geographic Coordinate System WGS 1984
WKID
Authority
Angular Unit
Prime Meridian
Datum
Spheroid
Semimajor Axis
Semiminor Axis
Inverse Flattening
4326
EPSG
Degree (0.0174532925199433)
Greenwich (0.0)
D WGS 1984
WGS 1984
6378137.0
6356752.314245179
298.257223563
I tried to project the data but it didn’t work but mapped properly in wgs.  But oddly the total acreage was different.

Use intersect tool, just one input layer - small polygons. If result come with no warning 'empty', you have overlaps

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the Question to report the coordinate reference of the the data, and how you calculated the areas.

Again, how did you calculate area?

Sorry.  I used the measurement tool calculating geodesic acres by feature.

Thank you to everyone who commented. I figured it out!   I merged the smaller polygons, switched the order of the layers and there was a slight difference.  I clipped it and came to the total in question.  Thanks again!
